# Empty or wrong values in App Script onFormSubmit event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form with some questions like:

[image]

This field is set as required. The problem is that I cannot see the results of this field in the corresponding spreadsheet:

[image]

I have a trigger to run a function (from the spreadsheet code editor) when an answer is sent from the form:

[image]

And this is the function triggered:

```
    function copyFormContents(e) {
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    }
```

And this is what I see in the log:

```
{
    "authMode": "FULL",
    "namedValues": {
        "My Question": [
            "",
            "Another answer"
        ]
    },
/ ******* /
}
```

As you can see, `My Question` appears with two entries, and sometimes empty. I have tried by switching the question to required and not, but this keeps happening. What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: What kind of data are you introducing in the answer?

Comment: Hello @FernandoLara I introduce text answers

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the same behavior using a new form?

Comment: In your showing response value, you show it as `"My Question": ["", "Another answer"]`. In this case, the array length is 2. But, in your Google Form, it seems that one question and one answer are shown. So, I'm worried that you might retrieve the response from another Google Form. How about this? But, if I misunderstood your provided information, I apologize.

Comment: Are you having two questions with the same title `My Question`?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, in the end I have 1. Unlinked the form, archive the corresponding tab and then added a new form. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Hi @idfurw, It seems that somebody accidentally deleted that question and then added it again to the form. So the array is showing some kind of `ghost` answer from the deleted question. I did as I explain above

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Victor M Perez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650325/victor-m-perez) it looks like the problem was solved by creating a new form and linking a new sheet to save the responses given the fact that deleting some questions was the actual root cause of the sheet showing incct data.

This is actually a common behavior that has appeared multiple times in different forums like in [Google's community](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/15713895/what-is-the-impact-if-you-make-improvements-to-the-form-when-some-have-already-replied).

There is no official documentation about this specific issue even though it is something expected as you can see in the explanation from the product expert in Google's community post.

As a recommendation I think it would be best to add this behavior to [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) for evaluation.